# how to login using username instead of email in laravel nova?

Tags: php, laravel-nova

In my existing laravel project, I handle logins with a username.

I've already replaced email with username on app\Nova\User.php

please help me how can I do login with username in laravel nova. 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have a look at this: https://stackoverflow.com/q/54334986/1039488

Answer (score 6):

I realize this is an old post but I haven't found anything more recent and I figured I'd show my method of handling this situation.

I've created a new controller

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\Nova;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class LoginController extends \Laravel\Nova\Http\Controllers\LoginController
{
    public function authLogin(Request $request)
    {
        $request->request->add(['username' => $request->email]);

        return $this->login($request);
    }
    public function username()
    {
        return 'username';
    }
}
```

and create a new route to override the nova route

```
Route::post('nova/login', 'Nova\LoginController@authLogin');
```

So you'll notice I extended the Nova controller. In our controller we'll add the username function that will return your 'username' field.
Now Nova will use the username field provided from your new function to login.

BUT...... it's not that simple buddy boy.

Now Nova thinks the form is going to pass your username field as 'username' provided by your new username function. 
So let's create a function called authLogin in our new controller. We'll grab the current form field 'email' and append a new 'username' field to our request. 
Now pass the request off to the login function provided by Nova with the new field appended to the request and let Nova handle the rest.

I'm not totally sure this method is a 'correct' way but it prevents from overriding core files or relying on copied core functions.

Answer (score 3):

After study about this issue, I've solved my own question.
here's the way I go.

app\Provider\NovaServiceProvider.php

```
    use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;

    //.....

    protected function routes()
    {
        $this->myLoginRoutes();
        Nova::routes()
                // ->withAuthenticationRoutes()
                ->withPasswordResetRoutes()
                ->register();        
    }

    /** ADD YOUR OWN LOGIN ROUTE */
    public function myLoginRoutes($middleware = ['web'])
    {
        Route::namespace('App\Nova\Http\Controllers\Auth')
            ->middleware($middleware)
            ->as('nova.')
            ->prefix(Nova::path())
            ->group(function () {
                Route::get('/login', 'LoginController@showLoginForm');
                Route::post('/login', 'LoginController@login')->name('login');
            });
    }
```

Copy 
`nova\src\resources\views\*`
to
`app\resources\views\vendor\nova\*` 
and you can free to modify what you want in view.

Copy 
`nova\src\Http\Controllers\LoginController.php`
to
`app\Nova\Http\Controllers\Auth\LoginController.php` 
and modify namespace to  App\Nova\Http\Controllers\Auth;

app\Nova\Http\Controllers\Auth\LoginController.php

```
    // ADD THIS METHOD TO OVERRIDE 
    public function username()
    {
        return 'username';
    }
```

assume you've changed `email` to `username` in users migration

Comment: Thanks, used this option as well, but you dont need to copy the entire LoginController. Just extend the original and add the username method override! And you also need to update your view to reflect the new field (e.g. replace all references to `email` to your new field name

Comment: @MarkMooibroek Could you provide an answer in wich you explain this?

Answer (score 1):

for me it helped to use the loadViewsFrom method in the boot function of the NovaServiceProvider

```
$this->loadViewsFrom(__DIR__.'/../resources/views/vendor/nova', 'nova');
```

Just copy the templates needed to app/resources/views/vendor/nova/...

See also: https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/packages#views

This change in addition to the change in the user model should do most of the trick

```
/**
* Get the login username to be used by the controller.
*
* @return string
*/
public function username()
{
   return 'username';
}
```

regards,

Andreas

Answer (score -2):

Add this into your

```
novaFolder\src\Http\Controllers
```

--

```
/**
 * Get the login username to be used by the controller.
 *
 * @return string
 */
public function username()
{
    return 'username';
}
```

This should do it, don't forget to add username column field into your table

Comment: Thank you, but do you have an idea to implement without touching the package.
Because It will be update and replace the edit

Comment: @ManITech i don't have an idea for that, yeah sometimes it sucks ,that we feels like have limitation when using nova , but i think its okay if we change it , just run your composer update or install once more every you edit the nova packages, don't edit it on vendor folder but edit it on nova extracted package after purchase/download. so it becoming new packages for composer