# Laravel Nova Redirect to a custom path after login

Tags: laravel-nova

I need to redirect user after login to a different place according to its role.

The logic is simple. I tried to put it in `redirectPath()` function in Nova `LoginController.php`, but I have a very weird behavior - sometimes after login I reach the right place, sometimes Nova redirects me to panel.

Any idea?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After a couple of hours of investigation, I figured out that the solution is quite simple.

All I had to do is to add the following function to nova LoginController:

```
protected function sendLoginResponse(Request $request)
{
    $request->session()->regenerate();

    $this->clearLoginAttempts($request);

    $redirectPath = $this->redirectPath();
    redirect()->setIntendedUrl($redirectPath);

    return redirect()->intended($redirectPath);
}
```

**Explanation:**

This function is implemented in [trait](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.traits.php) AuthenticatesUsers.

`intended` function (member of `Redirector` class) create a redirect response, based on previously intended location, and if not exists - on given url.

If no `url.intended` is set in session, user will be redirected to url generated by `LoginController::redirectPath`. **However**, if there an entry of `url.intended` does exist in session, we need to delete it in order to force redirecting user to the url we are interested in.

The only problem which I see is that we loose the feature of redirecting user to the same page he was before he was logged out. So it is a simple matter of choice as a developer...

Comment: This works when pages are loaded, but for some reason I found '/dashboard/main' path hard-coded in to app.js redirect. Worked around that with:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54426693/laravel-nova-redirect-from-dashboard

Answer (score 2):

The clean solution for `Nova 4` is here, I've not tested that on `Nova 3` or below.

Inside `NovaServiceProvider` update the below method

```
public function register()
{
    \Laravel\Nova\Nova::$initialPath = '/resources/users'; //update it to any valid nova path
}
```

Happy Coding :)

Comment: I haven't used Nova since 4 years ago, it's nice to see that new versions solve old problems, thanks! :-)

Comment: I think nova is best thing that happened in Laravel community, its super useful :)

Comment: FYI you can just do `Nova::initialPath('/a/b/c')`